State Management with RxJS in Angular (Undo Action)
I am learning state management concepts in Angular and am building a simple application using pure RxJS for study purposes. I’ve created a shopping cart application where I can add and remove products. I was able to implement adding and removing items from the cart state without issues. However, I would like to add a feature where, when an item is removed from the cart, this removal can be undone by restoring the previous state.
Can anyone help me with the best way to implement this feature using RxJS and Angular? Below is my current code:
export class CartStateService {
  private readonly initialState: CartState = { items: [] };
  private state$: BehaviorSubject<CartState> = new BehaviorSubject<CartState>(this.initialState);

  constructor() { }

  public get cartItems$(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
    return this.state$.asObservable().pipe(map(state => state.items));
  }

  public addToCart(item: CartItem): void {
    const items = [...this.state.items];
    const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id);

    if (index > -1) {
      items[index] = { ...items[index], quantity: items[index].quantity + item.quantity };
    } else {
      items.push(item);
    }

    this.setState({ items });
  }

  public removeFromCart(id: number): void {
    const items = this.state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  private get state(): CartState {
    return this.state$.getValue();
  }

  private setState(newState: Partial<CartState>): void {
    this.state$.next({ ...this.state, ...newState });
  }

  public clearCart(): void {
    this.setState(this.initialState);
  }

  public undoRemove(): void {
    // How do I implement undo functionality here?
  }
}


Any guidance on how to implement the "undo remove" functionality using RxJS, without manually storing the previous state in an array or variable, would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

We can use the rxjs operator pairwise. which records both the previous value and the current value. Then we use tap to store this previous value in the property of the service previousValue. You will notice I use structuredClone to take a deep clone of the state.
In Javascript arrays and objects are stored as references in memory and without this clone, the updates made to the current state also get set to the stored previous state.
public cartHistory$: Observable<any> = this.state$.pipe(
  pairwise(),
  tap((data: any) => {
    this.previousState = structuredClone(data[0]);
  })
);

So undo, is simply to apply the stored state to the current state and then making the stored state as null.
public undoRemove(): void {
  if (this.previousState) {
    this.state$.next(structuredClone(this.previousState));
    this.previousState = null;
  }
}

You will also notice I kept the history as a separate stream, I was not able to make it a single stream using the behaviourSubject, so we need to subscribe to it on the component, also we have to ensure it's unsubscribed.
export class App {
  name = '';
  quantity = 0;
  id = 0;
  cartStateService = inject(CartStateService);
  cartSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartSubscription.add(this.cartStateService.cartHistory$.subscribe());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cartSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

Full Code:
import { Component, inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
  Observable,
  map,
  pairwise,
  tap,
  Subscription,
} from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CartStateService {
  private readonly initialState: any = { items: [] };
  public previousState = null;
  private state$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(
    this.initialState
  );
  public cartHistory$: Observable<any> = this.state$.pipe(
    pairwise(),
    tap((data: any) => {
      this.previousState = structuredClone(data[0]);
    })
  );

  constructor() {}

  public get cartItems$(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.state$.asObservable().pipe(map((state: any) => state.items));
  }

  public addToCart(item: any): void {
    const items = [...this.state.items];
    const index = items.findIndex((i) => i.id === item.id);

    if (index > -1) {
      items[index] = {
        ...items[index],
        quantity: items[index].quantity + item.quantity,
      };
    } else {
      items.push(item);
    }

    this.setState({ items });
  }

  public removeFromCart(id: number): void {
    const items = this.state.items.filter((item: any) => item.id !== id);
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  private get state(): any {
    return this.state$.getValue();
  }

  private setState(newState: Partial<any>): void {
    this.state$.next({ ...this.state, ...newState });
  }

  public clearCart(): void {
    this.setState(this.initialState);
  }

  public undoRemove(): void {
    if (this.previousState) {
      this.state$.next(structuredClone(this.previousState));
      this.previousState = null;
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    {{cartStateService.previousState | json}}
    <hr/>
    @for(item of cartStateService.cartItems$ | async; track $index) {
      <div>{{item.name}} - ({{item.quantity}}) | <button (click)="cartStateService.removeFromCart(item.id)">X</button></div>
    }
    <hr/>
    name: <input [(ngModel)]="name"/><br/>
    quantity: <input [(ngModel)]="quantity" type="number"/><br/>
    <button (click)="addToCart()">add</button>
    <button (click)="cartStateService.clearCart()">clear</button>
    <button (click)="cartStateService.undoRemove()">undo</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = '';
  quantity = 0;
  id = 0;
  cartStateService = inject(CartStateService);
  cartSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartSubscription.add(this.cartStateService.cartHistory$.subscribe());
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cartSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  addToCart() {
    this.id++;
    this.cartStateService.addToCart({
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      quantity: this.quantity,
    });
    this.name = '';
    this.quantity = 0;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
